# Style my DataGrid to look like Windows Explorer Tiles

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image: https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/thinking/archive/2013/10/15/winforms-data-grid-new-windows-inspired-explorer-view.aspx]

Please look at the image and you'll see what I am trying to accomplish.

My datagrid currently looks like Excel (One column with an image and another with text). I would like it to look exactly like the image and have a Checkbox, Image and Text.

Here is my current XAML

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShortcutItems}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGridShortcut" GridLinesVisibility="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icons">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding BitMapIcon}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>    
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you considered editing your `<DataTemplate>` to do this?

Comment: Use a `ListView` or `ListBox`. A `DataGrid`  is not suitable for that.

Comment: Yea, just make a ListBox/View as the Item Template of an Accordion control or something and life will be easier for ya than your current route.

Comment: I should mention that I am totally new to WPF and XAML. Do you have sample code to show?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solutions to this?

Comment: No. It is unresolved